# How do I restrict pushing specific items through specific doors in Inform 7

Tags: inform7

I have a number of things I want to restrict from fitting through specific doors. So the chair is too big/heavy to carry but can be pushed through room to room in most cases. Except if the door is narrow. I can probably write specific code successfully to handle a specific case, but I want to handle this generically so I can have a number of bulky things and narrow doors.

The follow code functionally works, however the second noun ends up "nothing". I would like to use the name of the door in the direction of travel to respond to "push chair s" with the message "The chair is way too bulky to fit through the crack". Any ideas what I am doing wrong or another way of doing this?

```
A thing can be bulky. A thing is usually not bulky. 
A bulky thing is usually pushable between rooms.
A door can be narrow. A door is usually not narrow.

A bulky, enterable supporter called the chair is in room1. 

There is a narrow door called the crack. It is south of room1. 

Before going with a bulky thing through a narrow door:
    say "[The noun] is way too bulky to fit through [the second noun]." instead;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name the things in the rule preamble and use those names to print them in the rule.

```
Before going with a bulky thing (called the cargo) through a narrow door (called the obstacle):
    say "[The cargo] is way too bulky to fit through [the obstacle]." instead.
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! There seem to be some examples in the documentation, now that I know what to look for. But your example was exactly what I needed to understand this powerful technique! Thank you so much for the fast reply.